# LaTeX Templates in Russian

Tags: templates, babel, languages, russian

I am using LaTeX template for a thesis in English. Now I need to write my thesis in Russian using the same template. I added:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Everythig works perfectly apart from units. For example I want to write units in Russian  `25 ${м^3 с^{-1}}$` but I have 25 3-1. What else I need to add or remove in the index I added? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: By default there's no non-latin symbols in math mode. Use `25$\,\text{м}^3\text{с}^{-1}$` or `25\,м$^3$с$^{-1}$`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em I'm pretty sure that comment should really be an answer.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Thank you! Both lines work perfectly. Didn't know about this way of coding.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling, its length too small for real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default behaviour of math mode in latex don't allow to use non-ASCII symbols.

To use russian letters in math mode you can include them into macro `\text{}`:

```
25$\,\text{м}^3\text{с}^{-1}$
```

or put them outside:

```
25\,м$^3$с$^{-1}$
```

Another variant is to use package `mathtext`:

```
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
```

Option `warn` will show warnings on every cyrillic letter in formulae (that's useful for avoiding misprints).